# PHP - Echo and die

Tags: php, exit, die

I realize `or die("message")` prints the message and exits, but how can I echo the message and exit?

```
$resolveGet = mysql_query($sqlGet) or exit("<span style='padding-left:10px;'>No results matching search term provided.</span>");
```

Comment: What is the difference between "print" and "echo" in your eyes?

Comment: $resolveGet = mysql_query($sqlGet); 
exit($resolveGet || "<span style='padding-left:10px;>No results matching search term provided.</span>");

Comment: Well I was under the impression that echo is for use with outputting HTML (tags and such inclusive) whereas print solely outputs text to the HTML, but in looking that up I seem to be mistaken. Why then, would the code supplied not work?

Comment: What is the difference between `die` and `exit` in your eyes? (@arkascha :P)

Comment: Die and exit are equivalents, so it does not matter which you choose, and to answer to your question you can do echo and exit, or echo and die.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Which is a totally different question in my eyes. The OP compared "print" and "echo" which are similar, but not identically. Arg, too much stuff in my eyes, I have to rinse them, sorry.

Comment: _"Well I was under the impression that echo is for use with outputting HTML (tags and such inclusive) whereas print solely outputs text to the HTML"_ Hogwash. PHP does not care about HTML, not one bit. It is a preprocessor. It outputs bytes — that is it. Whether those bytes form a valid HTML document is up to you. A consequence of this is that neither `print` nor `echo` are magically "HTML-aware": they are, in fact, synonyms.

Comment: So why does the OP say: `I realize or die("message") prints the message` and then use exit instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You particular code can be also written differently, because what you have there is a logical **or**:

```
$resolveGet = mysql_query($sqlGet);
if (!$resolveGet ) {
    // exit("<span style='padding-left:10px;'>No results matching search term provided.</span>");

    // can rewrite this as 
    echo "<span style='padding-left:10px;'>No results matching search term provided.</span>";
   die(); // or exit;  // whatever
}
```